# Can a servlet filter's destory method be called by a shutdown hook or is there a better solution?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, destroy, shutdown-hook

I have a Java servlet filter that should clean up some resources whenever the filter is not longer used. This is achieved by implementing the `Filter.destory` method. Now I wonder if this method is also called when the entire servlet container is shutdown. Therefore, I was wondering if I should install a shutdown hook for this purpose. Or will the `Filter.destroy` method always called when the servlet container is shut down.

When I set a break point in my shutdown hook I never get to it. But I guess this is because IntelliJ already disconnected or some other reason like that. That makes it hard to find out by experimenting.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jetty 6.1.22 `Filter.destroy` was called during shutdown. The [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) just defines

> Called by the web container to indicate to a filter that it is being taken out of service.

You should test it without IntelliJ, in a "real" environment, with a stand-alone `tomcat` or `jetty`.

Anyway, just to be safe, you could clean up both in `Filter.destroy` and `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed`. 
In that case synchronize your filter clean up. And make sure, if you clean up twice, that the 2nd run does not fail with an exception etc.